# typescript assembly does not work when you start an assembly from Jenkins

Tags: node.js, typescript, jenkins, npm

I have an automation project on typescript, when I build and run the project from local Jenkins everything works correctly, but when I run it from Jenkins which is rolled out on the server in a virtual machine the project crashes with an error:

```
2023-06-29T12:03:03.341Z ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: file:///var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BT-Automation/wdio.conf.regression.ts: Cannot use import statement outside a module
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BT-Automation/wdio.conf.regression.ts:1
import type {Options} from '@wdio/types'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1177:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1221:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:962:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:165:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:192:25)
    at async CustomizedModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:246:24)
    at async ConfigParser.addConfigFile (file:///var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BT-Automation/node_modules/@wdio/config/build/lib/ConfigParser.js:85:36)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Local Jenkins is running on windows and remote Jenkins on ubuntu, but I tried to install Jenkins both directly in ubuntu and through Docker container the result is the same...

I tried the steps listed here https://v5.webdriver.io/docs/typescript.html

Please help who can, tried all the options that I found on the Internet, did not help

Comment: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` clearly indicates that you are trying to feed TypeScript into Node.js. Provide more details so that it is possible to locate where this is happening.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, the nodejs version.

Local project on 18.16.0 version, and on the remote server version 20, thank you)